# While plotting want two columns in Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In python I'm able to add 1 column in Y-axis

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
sb.lmplot(x="age", y="salary", data=df)
plt.show()
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to add 2 columns in Y-axis like `salary` and `name`. How to do this?

In X-axis- age.
In Y-axis- salary and name.

Comment: How working `sb.lmplot(x="age", y="salary", data=df, hue='name')` ?

Comment: tried to do this, but only the salary is considered as the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
sb.lmplot(x="age", y=["salary", "name"], data=df)
plt.show()
```

I believe this should work, but I have done little in this area so not 100%, can't really test until I finish work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an example of how you can do this, if I have understood correctly

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'series1': [1, 2, [enter image description here][1]3, 4, 5], 
                            'series2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                            'series3': [5, 6, 4, 3, 9]})

ax = df.plot(x="series1", y="series2", legend=False)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.plot(x="series1", y="series3", ax=ax2, legend=False, color="r")
ax.figure.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get this like where have you imported CSV file and what are those series for? And in those series, those numbers are like columns in CSV file?